# To load or not to load data for unit tests from external files

Tags: unit-testing, anti-patterns, unit-test-data

When unit testing I often find myself debating how much of the data I feed to, and expect back from my units under test, I should include in the actual test files.

The tradeoff I constantly struggling with is:

- If a large portion of the test (in code volume) consists of input and output data, it seems difficult to actually read the test, but I can easily see the actual in-and outputs.
- If I load the test data from files, I can easily test a bunch of variations on possible data input, easily reuse test data for multiple tests, but I have to leave the source code to look at another file to see what exactly the inputs are.

Is either one of these an anti-pattern?

Comment: What types of data?

Comment: @JonReid: Mostly text.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To answer your question directly - no, I don't believe either is an anti-pattern when used correctly.

--- More verbose answer ---

From my experience, I think this depends heavily on the goal of your test. Here's the rule of thumb I've used in the past and it's helped me decide:

Are you actually testing a small unit of code? (A true unit test)

If yes, then I've found it's much easier to create the data inside the test itself exactly because I can see what is being passed in. In these cases, I will usually look for a [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/)-like library to use because I find that it makes creating and maintaining the test data easier. That's a personal preference though - use whatever makes your job easier.

If no, then you're probably actually testing the system itself. In these cases, I often do load data from an external source, the reasons here being:

1. This test isn't about code clarity for programmers (although that is still important - someone has to maintain this), it's about running enough different types of data through the entire chunk of the system to be reasonably sure it works.
2. Often I will write the plumbing code to load and use the test data, but the data itself is created by someone else (usually a QA staff member in my case). These people aren't usually programmers so I can't expect them to be editing code.

So long answer short, it depends on what you're testing and why. Both approaches are useful and have their place - choose what works best for your situation.

Answer (score 9):

I don't see a trade-off here. Source code is supposed to describe algorithms, or at least business logic, not big amounts of data. If you write a Fourier transform, you want to verify that a sinus tone is correctly mapped to a single peak, a mixed sound to more peaks etc., but for that it is completely sufficient to feed a file named `sinus.wav` into the routine and verify that the output structure is what you expect.

Sure, technically you don't have an immediate assurance that `sinus.wav` really does contain a sinus tone, but as you said, listing the 100,000 amplitude values in the source doesn't really give you that either - in fact, it is *worse*, because you can at least play an external file with an audio player to check, while data values buried in source code are essentially impossible to do anything with.